# Is it really necessary for APs to constantly send beacon frames (always be in "discovery mode")?

Tags: wireless, ieee-802.11, power, safety

Why do wireless APs constantly transmit (e.g., with a beacon interval of 10×/sec.), even when no devices are connected to them? Doesn't that just cause needless RFI? Is it really necessary to constantly be sending beacon frames? Is there a way to disable this? (I don't think hiding SSID disables sending beacons.)

Comment: @JesseP. It would remember the AP and transmit to it awake it.

Comment: The most basic reason: the 802.11 spec says so. The logic behind it is so clients (associated or not) can tell the BSSID (station) is still there. Too many missed beacons and the station is marked as down (may be off, or just out of range.) Messing with the default beacon interval can lead to all manner of weird problems.

Comment: @RickyBeam Long beacon intervals can be a good thing, though; cf. [this](https://routerguide.net/beacon-interval-best-optimal-setting-improve-wireless-speed/).

Comment: @Geremia, long beacon intervals can be **very** bad though, since there are quite a few client devices that don't respond well to long beacon intervals (especially consumer devices). The "article" you link does not contain nearly enough information nor any truly valid reason to change the beacon interval. Frankly, there is so little gain from doing so and there are quite a few far more effective adjustments that can be made to a wireless configuration with fewer potential risks than tuning the beacon interval.

Comment: @YLearn "_there are quite a few far more effective adjustments_" Such as? And "far more effective" for what?

Comment: @Geremia, effective for increasing airtime efficiency, which you should know since you are asking about it. Such as? Additional APs on different channels and better coverage, tuning of data rates, disable support for unnecessary legacy protocols, disabling use of RTS-CTS (if enabled) or at least utilizing CTS-to-self, and so on. That however is a completely different question and answer.

Comment: @YLearn How is "airtime efficiency" measured?

Comment: @YLearn I'm interested in power conservation and minimizing RF transmitting.

Comment: @Geremia, as I said earlier, "*That however is a completely different question and answer.*" You have stretched the comments farther than intended already. Please either ask in chat or ask new questions.

Comment: @YLearn Here's how an Asus router describes the beacon interval: «Beacon Interval means the period of time between one beacon and the next one. The default value is 100 (the unit is millisecond, or 1/1000 second). Lower the Beacon Interval to improve transmission performance in unstable environment or for roaming clients, but it will be power consuming.» Is this accurate?

Comment: @Geremia, not from the AP side as beacons are no more power consuming than any other TX traffic. It may have a power consumption effect on some client devices that wake up every beacon interval to check for traffic. However, increasing the beacon interval can also result in lost data for the same types of clients if the AP doesn't have enough buffer space to store any data for those clients before the next beacon interval.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Why do wireless APs constantly transmit (e.g., with a beacon interval of 10×/sec.), even when no devices are connected to them?

Just because an AP doesn't have any client devices associated to them, doesn't mean there are no client devices that would be "interested" in associating to them. In particular, this is useful in deployments that have multiple APs as this helps to provide information to clients so they can make decisions about roaming.

Additionally, beacon frames perform a number of different functions in addition to discovery. They serve as a timing source, provide other information to 802.11 devices, allow for power saving features in client devices, etc.

Answer (score 2):

A beacon is required in order for clients to know when a particular AP/SSID is nearby and ready for connections.  Without that, the client would never know there's available WiFi nearby, regardless of possibly having previously connected to said SSID.  You can disable a beacon by disabling/deleting the associated SSID, or you can simply adjust the beacon rate so it's not 10x/second or whatever yours is set to.

You can read more about the beacon frame and its purpose [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beacon_frame?wprov=sfla1)

Comment: An AP can lack an SSID?

Comment: Yeah. They lack SSIDs when they're first unpacked (when they're new) most of the time.

Comment: Technically, yes, an AP needs at least one SSID. But it doesn't have to include it in the beacon. (i.e. "hidden" SSID) If it doesn't have an SSID, nothing can connect to it, and thus its radio should be silent.

Comment: @RickyBeam Wrong.  Cisco AiroNet APs, for example, do not have any SSIDs configured on them out of the box.  Many other APs are the same way.  The only APs I've ever seen that come WITH an SSID out of the box have been consumer-grade routers with WiFi built in or wireless bridges.

Comment: @RickyBeam To further my point, here is an excerpt from a Cisco AiroNet doc.  "Beginning with Cisco IOS Release 12.3(8)JA, access point radios are disabled and no default SSID is 
assigned. This was done in order to prevent unauthorized users to access a customer wireless network 
through an access point having a default SSID and no security settings. You must create an SSID before 
you can enable the access point radio interfaces."

Comment: "**radios are disabled**" "**You must create an SSID before you can enable the access point radio interfaces**" Without an SSID, it's not a usable, beaconing, AP.

Comment: @RickyBeam I didn't say it was usable for wireless access - I said it can have NO SSID configured, which was what the OP asked about, and is technically accurate. An AiroNet with or without an SSID is still a wireless access-point... It just hasn't been fully configured yet to be usable wirelessly.